# The invite could not be sent as Google Cloud Platform is disabled for the account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I use google cloud platform, trying to add someone to the project as owner,  it tolds me that
**The invite could not be sent as Google Cloud Platform is disabled for the account. Please contact the G Suite admin for the account to enable it.**
This project is created by other people and I am the second onwer. 
Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would ask the GSuite Super Admin (for the domain of the person you are inviting) to look into [GCP service in the Admin Console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9197205?hl=en).

Sounds like GCP was intentionally disable for the organizaton or at user level